# How to multiply the y-axis values of a histogram by a fixed number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have a list of data to plot using histograms. I want to scale the `y-axis` of each plot separately. If I do like the following, it scales each plot's `y-axis` by 10.

```
protocols = {}
types = {"data1": "data1.csv", "data2": "data2.csv", "data3": "data3.csv"}

for protname, values in protocols.items():
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.hist(values["col_data"], facecolor='blue', alpha=0.9, label=protname,align='left')
    y_vals = ax1.get_yticks()
    ax1.set_yticklabels(['{:3.0f}'.format(x * 10) for x in y_vals])
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

However, I want the scaling to be separate for each histogram. I tried it as the following but it doesn't seem to be working as intended.

```
for protname, values in protocols.items():
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.hist(values["col_data"], facecolor='blue', alpha=0.9, label=protname,align='left')
    y_vals = ax1.get_yticks()
    ax1.set_yticklabels(['{:3.0f}'.format(x * 10) for x in y_vals if protname=="data1" and ['{:3.0f}'.format(x * 10) for x in y_vals if protname=="data2" and ['{:3.0f}'.format(x * 15) for x in y_vals if protname=="data3"]]])

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

If we try ONLY for one plot as `ax1.set_yticklabels(['{:3.0f}'.format(x * 10) for x in y_vals if protname=="data2"])` it applies the changes only to the second plot and leave the others blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I'd be interested in why you want to manipulate the y-axis values, as the histogram values are those of your data - I don't see a reason for changing it without loosing the meaning for your data.

That said, my next question would be generally if you intentionally set `plt.subplots` *inside* your for-loop, because one use case for this command is in fact creating several subplots into one figure - perhaps you'll think about that later...

However, the easiest way to apply different factors at different iterations is simply to add them as another list into your loop with `zip`:

```
factors = [10, 10, 15]
for (protname, values), m in zip(protocols.items(), factors):
    ...
    ax1.set_yticklabels(['{:3.0f}'.format(x * m) for x in y_vals])
    ...
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I replace `m` with the `.format()` function I posted. TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you did. `m` represents the value you want to use - a different one in each iteration. It's not the list, it's `10` in the first run, `10` in the second and `15` in the third in the above example.

Comment: Thank you. Accepted answer!

Comment: You're welcome - and for the sake of interest: would you mind to explain a reason for this kind of manipulation?

Comment: I was just trying to compare if my prediction changes when we scale the values or not and now i learnt that it doesn't!